# python - extract 4 digits before the 2nd last of a variable

Tags: python, python-2.7, character

Using python 27, I have a variable with up to 30 consecutive digits, no other characters. I want the last 6 characters, and the first 4 of those. I tried  `len` and

```
len([c for c in s if c.isdigit()]) ## 3
```

For example: in  `var1 = 123456789123456781121230` I want to print the 1212 at the end, before the 30.

Comment: So is your variable a string or an integer?

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
var1 = 123456789123456781121230
print str(var1)[-6:-2]
```

Or, if you need the result as an integer:

```
integer_result = int(str(var1)[-6:-2])
```

Answer (score 0):

use modulo `%` to get the reminder of 1,000,000 which result in 6 digits number, then divide by 100 to trip two number, dividing by an int will result a number without digits after the dot.

It's a much faster and cleaner way to do it than converting the int to a string.

```
>>> x = var1 % 1000000 / 100
>>> x
1212L
>>> int(x)
1212
>>> str(x)
'1212'
```

Comment: Please give us some details!  This isn't very helpful the way it's written.  Explain some.  At least write something like `Here's a way to do it:`.